# SQL - INSERT if not exist, otherwise UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to use the Steam API to login to my site, I want to make a database entry everytime a user logs in however, at first I kept getting duplicate inserts every time when using this code:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_users (steam_id, username, trade, welcome) VALUES ('".$steamprofile['steamid']."','".$steamprofile['personaname']."','0', '1')
```

Then I tried some code where it would update if the entry exists, but still I ended up with a new entry despite this.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_users (steam_id, username, trade, welcome) VALUES ('".$steamprofile['steamid']."','".$steamprofile['personaname']."','0', '1')
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username=('".$steamprofile['personaname']."')";
```

What I really need is a primary key for the duplicate, so when it checks for a dupe, it looks at the steamid not the user_id (Primary key and AI in database)

**Thanks for any help :D**

Comment: Make `steam_id` a unique index in the table.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for that, it worked :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so anyone else wanting a solution to a similar problem, there must be a unique index in your database so the php can decide to insert or update, in my case I used their steamid which never changes.

**Thanks to @Barmar for the answer**